# Retrieve Github repository name using GitPython

Tags: python-3.6, gitpython

Is there a way to get the repository name using GitPython?

```
repo = git.Repo.clone_from(repoUrl, ".", branch=branch)
```

I can't seem to find any properties attached to the repo object which has this information. It might be that I misunderstand how github/GitPython works.

Answer (score 19):

Simple, compact, and robust that works with remote `.git` repos:

```
 from git import Repo

 repo = Repo(repo_path)

 # For remote repositories
 repo_name = repo.remotes.origin.url.split('.git')[0].split('/')[-1]

 # For local repositories
 repo_name = repo.working_tree_dir.split("/")[-1]
```

Comment: `working_tree_dir` is `None` for bare repositories.

Answer (score 6):

May I suggest:

```py
remote_url = repo.remotes[0].config_reader.get("url")  # e.g. 'https://github.com/abc123/MyRepo.git'
os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(remote_url))[0]  # 'MyRepo'
```

Comment: repo.remotes.origin.url.split('.git')[0].split('/')[-1]

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to do it. However, I built this function to retrieve the repository name given an URL (you can see it in action [here](https://github.com/ishepard/pydriller)):

```
def get_repo_name_from_url(url: str) -> str:
    last_slash_index = url.rfind("/")
    last_suffix_index = url.rfind(".git")
    if last_suffix_index < 0:
        last_suffix_index = len(url)

    if last_slash_index < 0 or last_suffix_index <= last_slash_index:
        raise Exception("Badly formatted url {}".format(url))

    return url[last_slash_index + 1:last_suffix_index]
```

Then, you do:

```
get_repo_name_from_url("https://github.com/ishepard/pydriller.git")     # returns pydriller
get_repo_name_from_url("https://github.com/ishepard/pydriller")         # returns pydriller
get_repo_name_from_url("https://github.com/ishepard/pydriller.git/asd") # Exception
```

Comment: I did something similar: `repoName = repoUrl.rsplit("/")[1].split(".")[0]` but your way is more robust I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The `working_dir` property of the `Repo` object is the absolute path to the git repo. To parse the repo name, you can use the `os.path.basename` function.

```
>>> import git
>>> import os
>>>
>>> repo = git.Repo.clone_from(repoUrl, ".", branch=branch)
>>> repo.working_dir
'/home/user/repo_name'
>>> os.path.basename(repo.working_dir)
'repo_name'
```

Comment: This gives you the name of the folder. While the default when you clone a repo is to name the folder the same as the repo, it can be changed by the user.